# Maintain User Loggedin and LoggedOut Info In Mongo Db and express js,node js ,Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

**scenario**
         If user LoggedIn More than one device send notification to user for that i have used one flag in collection called **Logged In** true or false. when user logged out i can easily trigger LoggedIn as false but if the user closed the browser or any network problem happen how to identify which user session end.is there is any way to do?

Comment: U have the IP of each device.Why not use this ?

Comment: We can  Easily track IP,But when network problem occur user might be reconnect the network and ip change from previous?

Comment: U can use your session coockie